# Seeking a closed-form solution of a system of nonlinear trigonometric equations (converting Euler angles to spherical)

Tags: trigonometry, closed-form, rotations, nonlinear-system, symbolic-computation

Following [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/MathHelp/comments/bra1j9/closedform_solution_for_converting_spherical/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56233929/4999991) questions, I want to solve the system of nonlinear trigonometrical equations (as part of an inverse kinematics calculation):

$$\begin{align}
\sin{\phi} \sin{\gamma} &= \sin\alpha \cos\theta_1 \cos\theta_2 + \cos\alpha \sin\theta_2\\
\cos{\phi} &= \cos\alpha \cos\theta_1 \cos\theta_2 - \sin\alpha \sin\theta_2 \\
\sin\phi \cos\gamma &= \sin\theta_1 \cos\theta_2
\end{align}$$

for $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ given the $\gamma$, $\phi$, and $\alpha$.

I think there should be closed form solution.

I tried `Python-SymPy`:

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import symbols, sin, cos, tan

alpha, gamma, phi, theta1, theta2 = symbols('alpha gamma phi theta_1 theta_2')

eqs = (sin(alpha) * cos(theta1) + tan(theta2) * cos(alpha) - tan(gamma) * sin(theta1),
      cos(alpha) * cos(theta1) * cos(theta2) - sin(alpha) * sin(theta2) - cos(phi))
solve(eqs, (theta1, theta2))
```

However, the interpreter never finishes.

I would appreciate if you could help me know if the above system of equations has explicit solution.

Comment: If this is a numpy question, it would be best served on StackOverflow.

Comment: OK, try editing the question to start _from the beginning,_ explaining exactly what you are trying to do, what each symbol means, where you got the expressions on each side of your equations, what those expressions mean, and why you think they should be equal. While you're at it you should comment the code you posted on StackOverflow; how is anyone supposed to guess what you think your "Rodrigues" function is supposed to do? Lack of explanation by you may have something to do with why you didn't get any answers there yet.

Comment: Dear @dantopa this is not a numpy question and the only reason I have used the python-sympy code is just to include what I have done so far.

Comment: Dear @DavidK thanks for the extensive comment. I added the link to [Rodrigues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula). what I'm trying to do is to find a closed form solution to the system of equations mentioned above. How I go those is that I have a series of rotations which now I want to calculate the inverse kinematics.

Comment: The equations at hand can be rewritten as
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\sin \phi \sin\gamma \\
\cos \phi\\
\sin \phi \cos\gamma
\end{bmatrix}
=
R(\alpha)
\begin{bmatrix}
\sin\theta_2\\
\cos\theta_1 \cos\theta_1\\
\sin\theta_1 \cos\theta_2
\end{bmatrix}
\quad\text{where}\quad
R(\alpha) =\begin{bmatrix} 
\cos\alpha  & \sin\alpha & 0\\
-\sin\alpha & \cos\alpha & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Try multiply both sides on the left by $R(\alpha)^{-1} = R(-\alpha)$.

Comment: @achillehui That's so very nearly a complete answer it seems a shame not to put it in the answer section. (Although I'm sure you meant one of those $\theta_1$s to be $\theta_2$ instead.)

Comment: @achillehui this is great. how ignorant of me that I didn't think of this before! 

Answer (score 1):

(too long for comment)

The Euler angles define the position of a 3D Euclidean reference system rotated wrt a base one.

The spherical coordinates define the position of one (unit vector), for instance the $x'$ axis of the rotated system: the position of the other two (rotation around $x'$) is not known.

So the correspondence is not univoque. You shall specify better what actually is your aim.

I saw now that you mention Rodrigues' formula: that is in fact relative to the rotation of a (unit) vector around another unit vector (axis of rotation). 
Practically the rotation of a point on earth around another point on earth.
So how is your problem formulated in this "environment" ?

*From your self-answer*, and taking as reference the [Geographic convention for Spherical Coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#In_geography)
with $\theta_1$ as longitude and $\theta_2$ as latitude, 
it is now clear that you want to
 - take a vector in such a reference system 
$$
{\bf v} =\left( {1,\theta _1 ,\theta _2 } \right) = \left( {\matrix{
   {\cos \theta _2 \cos \theta _1 }  \cr 
   {\cos \theta _2 \sin \theta _1 }  \cr 
   {\sin \theta _2 }  \cr 
 } } \right)
$$
 - exchange its components according to the matrix
$$
{\bf E} = \left( {\matrix{
   0 & 0 & 1  \cr 
   1 & 0 & 0  \cr 
   0 & 1 & 0  \cr 
 } } \right)
$$
which has a negative determinant and so includes a reflection;
 - rotate it around the original reference polar axis ($z$) of an angle $- \alpha$ (in the right-hand convention, i.e. eastward)
$$
{\bf R}_{\,{\bf z}} ( - \alpha ) = \left( {\matrix{
   {\cos \alpha } & { + \sin \alpha } & 0  \cr 
   { - \sin \alpha } & {\cos \alpha } & 0  \cr 
   0 & 0 & 1  \cr 
 } } \right)
$$
 - exchange back its components
$$
{\bf E}^{\, - \,{\bf 1}}  = \left( {\matrix{
   0 & 1 & 0  \cr 
   0 & 0 & 1  \cr 
   1 & 0 & 0  \cr 
 } } \right)
$$
 - rename the resulting longitude ${\theta '}_1$ as $\gamma$, and take the azimut angle $\phi$ 
in place of the resulting latitude ${\theta '}_2$ , i.e. $\phi = \pi/2-{\theta '}_2$.

Is that your goal?

Comment: Dear G Cab, probably I have misunderstood the term "Euler angles". It is actually a series of rotations as I have explained [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/MathHelp/comments/bra1j9/closedform_solution_for_converting_spherical/). my aim is to find the closed-form solution to those equations.

Comment: Well, the question remains on what rotations you are actually considering (there are [many possible definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles)) and how you want to relate these to the position of a single vector

Comment: $\phi$ and $\gamma$ are the spherical angles of the $y$ unit vector. Anyway, I think the problem is solved now.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the great comment by [achille hui](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/59379/achille-hui) we can write the system of equations as:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} \sin \phi \sin\gamma \\ \cos \phi\\ \sin \phi \cos\gamma \end{bmatrix} = R(\alpha) \begin{bmatrix} \sin\theta_2\\ \cos\theta_1 \cos\theta_2\\ \sin\theta_1 \cos\theta_2 \end{bmatrix}
$$

where $R(\alpha)$ is the rotation matrix of:

$$
R(\alpha) =\begin{bmatrix}  \cos\alpha  & \sin\alpha & 0\\ -\sin\alpha & \cos\alpha & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\\ \end{bmatrix}
$$

and its invert is

$$
R^{-1}(\alpha) = R(-\alpha) = \begin{bmatrix}  \cos\alpha  & -\sin\alpha & 0\\ \sin\alpha & \cos\alpha & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\\ \end{bmatrix}
$$

now the equation can be rewritten as:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} \sin\theta_2\\ \cos\theta_1 \cos\theta_2\\ \sin\theta_1 \cos\theta_2 \end{bmatrix} =
\displaystyle \left[\begin{matrix}- \sin{\left(\alpha \right)} \cos{\left(\phi \right)} + \sin{\left(\gamma \right)} \sin{\left(\phi \right)} \cos{\left(\alpha \right)}\\\sin{\left(\alpha \right)} \sin{\left(\gamma \right)} \sin{\left(\phi \right)} + \cos{\left(\alpha \right)} \cos{\left(\phi \right)}\\\sin{\left(\phi \right)} \cos{\left(\gamma \right)}\end{matrix}\right]
$$

which is calculated through the python-sympy command of

```
Matrix([[cos(alpha), -sin(alpha), 0],
       [sin(alpha), cos(alpha), 0],
       [0, 0, 1]]) * Matrix([[sin(phi) * sin(gamma)], [cos(phi)], [sin(phi) * cos(gamma)]])
```

and as a result we get:

$$\tan{\theta_1} = \frac{\sin{\phi} \cos{\gamma}}{\sin{\alpha} \sin{\gamma} \sin{\phi} + \cos{\alpha} \cos{\phi}}$$

and

$$
\sin{\theta_2} = \sin{\left(\gamma \right)} \sin{\left(\phi \right)} \cos{\left(\alpha \right)} - \sin{\left(\alpha \right)} \cos{\left(\phi \right)}
$$